# If B extends A, one cannot cast List<A> to List<B> (makes sense), but then why can one cast List<? extends A> to List<B>?

Tags: java, generics, casting

If a class `B` extends class `A`, one cannot cast `List<A>` to `List<B>` (cast 1 below). This makes sense, because if it were allowed, then one could read a `B` from the list even if it contained none.

However, in the code below, cast 2 from `List<? extends A>` to `List<B>` causes a warning. Shouldn't it generate an error for the same reason as before? In the code, the list only contains one object that is an `A` but not a `B`, and yet it is in a list deemed `List<B>`.

```
package test;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TypeLowerBoundCasting {

    static class A {}
    static class B extends A {}

    static void method1() {
        List<A> listOfAs = new LinkedList<A>();
        listOfAs.add(new A());
        // List<B> listOfAsAsListOfBs = (List<B>) listOfAs ; // cast 1: compiler error
        // B b = listOfAsAsListOfBs.get(0); // that would be bad
    }

    static void method2() {
        LinkedList<A> listOfAs = new LinkedList<A>();
        listOfAs.add(new A());
        List<? extends A> listOfAExtensions = listOfAs;
        List<B> listOfAsAsListOfBs = (List<B>) listOfAExtensions; // cast 2: warning, but compiles
        B b = listOfAsAsListOfBs.get(0); // that IS bad; causes a run-time error.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because while a `List<B>` could never be a `List<A>`, a `List<B>` could be a `List<? extends A>`? Casting is telling the compiler you know more than it - you can always do `List<B> bs = (List<B>) (List)` to force cast generics types - again, this will issue several warnings and is generally a Bad Idea TM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List<? extends A>` *might* be a `List<B>`, so you can cast:

```
List<? extends A> list = new ArrayList<B>(); // lose type information
List<B> result = (List<B>) list; // regain type information
```

Similar to how you can do:

```
Object o = "Hello World!"; // lose type information
String s = (String) o; // regain type information
```

Unfortunately, the first cast is unchecked. But a cast in that place is still a valid option, as you can see.

---

But a `List<A>` can never actually be a `List<B>` (unless you abuse raw types), because `List<A>` is not assignable from a `List<B>` (i.e. `List<B>` does not 'extend' `List<A>`) so you can't cast:

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<B>(); // Only works with: (List<A>) (List) new ArrayList<B>();
```